# VB.net Connection Failed database MySql

Tags: mysql, vb.net, connection

I have problems when running software that has been developed using Visual Basic and mysql database. The connection runs perfectly on the codingan, but the problem is that the database connection is often lost when running the application at the time of data access, and suddenly the connection fails

Please help me to find a solutuon

[image]

Comment: Can you show what code you are using to make the check for the connection?

Comment: Sub koneksi()        Try
            constring = New MySqlConnection("server=localhost;user id=root;database=sada")
            constring.Open()

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Connection Failed")
        End Try
    End Sub

Comment: I use this code in the module

Comment: Include that as part of the question too.

Comment: I use this connection code in my application, but the problem is. sometimes when the program is run, a notification suddenly appears in the attachment, even though previously there were no problems

Comment: No no. I meant as part of your question to everyone, include the code that you are using so that everyone can see it. You can reedit your question.